# Filling in timeline from two workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, timeline

I have created a timeline in a general worksheet of Excel as follows:

[image]

Now the remaining thing for me to do is to fill it with content. For this I have a different file. See the image below:

[image]

I would like to find a way to fill in (with conditional formatting) the timeline from figure 1. How could I do this? There are different sections to the time line.
I would prefer to do this without a VBA Macro but simple with equations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear in your "timeline" screenshot whether the time's also include date information, so I made the assumption they don't.  In which case you'll have to add a helper column to your "different file" where I'll assume "Starting Time" is in `A1`:

```
=ROUND(A2-INT(A2),6)
```

I put this formula in column `D` for the following example:

[image: conditional format times screenshot]

Select `C1` > Conditional Formatting > New Rule... > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > [this formula]:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(ROUND(C$1,6),$B$2:$B$5,0)))
```

OK, now change the "Applies to" for that condition, to

```
=$C$1:$S$10
```

The `ROUND` is necessary because when the timestamps are compared, they cannot `MATCH` because they're fractions of days.

Obviously this won't match your data perfectly because not enough information was supplied in the question.